# StumbleUpon Toolbar messing up my scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Viewing my site with the Stumbleupon Toolbar in Chrome activated causes some strange scripting errors (some buttons no longer having click handlers and some elements not being rendered where they are supposed to be rendered).

The problem does not exist when using the Stumbleupon Toolbar in a different browser or if the user is operating in Chrome with the Stumbleupon Toolbar deactivated.

Any ideas?